# Showing Cast error while converting a pdf to RDD[string] in Apache Spark,Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Getting Answer for first println and not for rddwithPath.

```
val conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(FileInputFormat.INPUT_DIR, filePath)
val data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[PdfInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text])
data.foreach(x => println(x))

val rddwithPath = data.asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]].mapPartitionsWithInputSplit { (inputSplit, iterator) ⇒
  val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
  iterator.map { tpl ⇒ (file.getPath.toString, tpl._2.toString) }
}
data.foreach(x => println(s"line no.: ${x._1}, data: ${x._2}"))
rddwithPath.foreach(println)
```

**error is :**

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD
>       at Test.PDFReader$.main(PDFReader.scala:26)"

Comment: Why didn't you use `binaryFiles` and then for example Tica to parse PDF?

Comment: yes I tried that also and got out .but If I read in this way how its getting out

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? Casts don't do conversions, they just "re-interpret" the value as the new type  and NewHadoopRDD and Hadoop aren't related to allow you do to that. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

Comment: why I am using this is inorder to set a generalised way because for txt folder I am reading this as
val text = sc.hadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], sc.defaultMinPartitions)

    var rddwithPath = text.asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]].mapPartitionsWithInputSplit { (inputSplit, iterator) ⇒
      val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]
      val ss = iterator.map { tpl ⇒ (file.getPath.toString, tpl._2.toString)}
      ss
    }.reduceByKey((a,b) => a)

Comment: It doesn't matter what else you are doing, You can't cast an `NewHadoopRDD` to a `HadoopRDD`, and I have no idea why you think you can.  The exception you are getting exactly describes the problem, In  your code in the comment (which you really should add to your question), you are using `sc.hadoopFile` which presumably returns a `HadoopRDD` anyway so everything works.

Comment: Thanks everyone .  I got that answer with NewHadoopRDD